# Где взять исходники

Tags: c++, linux, opensource

Нужны исходные коды программ типа GParted или Терминал или чего-то под Linux. Но обязытельно чтобы в этой программе нужно было авторизовываться. Где взять такие исходники? Желательно на C++, но не обязательно.

Comment: /usr/src, однако

Comment: "Но обязытельно чтобы в этой программе нужно было авторизовываться." Что вы хотите этим сказать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот исходники Gparted: https://github.com/GNOME/gparted.
ПС остальное можно в google найти (он бесплатный, без регистрации и СМС)